# White screen phonegap in android device

Tags: android, cordova, root, barcode-scanner

So I am building a phonegap application where I use BarcodeScanner plugin. I rooted my device and use 2 commands:

1. command-1: service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui
2. command-2: am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService

Command-1 makes the bottom and top bars disappear.
Command-2 make the bars reappear.

After I started using this commands I keep getting white screens. Here is how:

I start my application, and the command-1 is run initially. In my application I can press a button to scan barcodes. So after I press the scan button I am redirected to another page with the barcodescanner interface, after I have scanned I am redirected to one another page. 
So initially it works fine. However If I use a button to make the bars reappear and after that reopen my application, things get bad. After I press scan button, and the barcode is scanned I get white screen. I dont know how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Comment: I had a similar problem where after certain activities were carried out, my phonegap app would "restart". You might want to look at savedInstanceState in your MainActivity class and see what your app is tries to do onResume or onPause, or if savedInstanceState == null. It might be that your app is re-entering the code and has no instruction as to what to do next